# gnuplot: same grid intervals, round lable values, draw lines

Tags: gnuplot

few questions on gnuplot:

1. How to set the same intervals of grid tics (same grid step) both in value and in pixels on both axes?  Tics interval is set manually, but autoscale method is wanted (if different initial data has different max values) with condition that step and min-max will be the same for x and y. If it possible in gnuplot. Maybe request is very special.
2. How to round label values? (if data is 1.5000 , label is 1.5000, but want: 1  1.5  2  2.5 etc, floor($1) and int($1) doesn't work?).
3. Is it possible to insert a line connecting points with the max distance of 0,0 (as in the example picture) (maybe there should be a condition, if x^2+y^2 = max, then draw a line)
4. How to highlight with a bold line those grid lines that intersect 0,0? Or draw separate lines (done, but maybe better way exists)?

Example:

[[image: example][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIuWx.png)

My graph:

[image: my graph]

```
set terminal windows 0 position 20,20
set terminal windows size 800,800

set xtics 0.25
set ytics 0.25

set grid xtics ytics

set size ratio -1 # now length of axes on monitor are ~ 17.5 cm and 18.5 cm, not square
#set size square

set style circle radius graph 0.25/2

maxv=1
set yrange [-maxv:maxv]
set xrange [-maxv:maxv]

set ylabel 'Y' font ", 11"
set xlabel 'X' font ", 11"

filename='file1.txt'

set arrow from 0, graph 0 to 0, graph 1 lc 'gray' nohead


plot 0 lc 'gray' notitle, \
filename using ($2-$3):($4-$5):(floor($1)) \
with labels tc lt 1 point pt 7 offset char 1,1 notitle, \
filename using ($2-$3):($4-$5) w l lc black notitle
```

version 5.2

data:

```
-6.0    -10.14  -10.10  14.92   14.86
-5.5    -16.75  -16.70  25.60   25.50
-5.0    -20.62  -20.53  30.65   30.49
-4.5    -26.56  -26.42  38.00   37.74
-4.0    -27.80  -27.55  38.25   37.84
-3.5    -33.33  -32.94  43.80   43.19
-3.0    -33.96  -33.37  44.04   43.19
-2.5    -38.02  -37.20  46.64   45.85
-2.0    -38.97  -38.07  44.53   44.18
-1.5    -30.61  -29.97  34.93   35.03
-1.0    -22.60  -22.00  24.24   24.22
-0.5    -7.65   -7.25   5.70    5.47
0.0      2.87    2.84    -3.67   -3.66
0.5      17.62   17.21   -19.79  -19.57
1.0      17.37   16.77   -17.00  -16.95
1.5      30.11   29.50   -32.04  -32.20
2.0      34.69   33.99   -40.26  -40.04
2.5      38.21   37.44   -45.19  -44.37
3.0      34.26   33.67   -42.68  -41.83
3.5      26.69   26.31   -34.85  -34.24
4.0      30.04   29.79   -41.45  -41.03
4.5      20.62   20.48   -28.99  -28.74
```

Comment: Can you please provide the data? It's easier to propose something working and test _with_ realistic data.

Comment: of course. Data added

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered?

Comment: Problem solved, Question answered, thank you

Comment: ok, then please mark the answer as helpful/accepted to indicate that your problem was solved.

Comment: Could you please say how to mark it? Don't see this option.

Comment: there is an up-arrow and a check mark (only for the one who asked) on the top left side of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You set the same interval of tics and grid via `set xtics 0.25` and `set ytics 0.25` as you did. If you want the unit of x and y axes to have the same length (independent of the terminal aspect ratio) you `set size ratio -1` as you did. You can easily check, e.g. if you set `set xrange[-2:2]`. Check `help size`. If your graph on the screen has 17.5 cm x 18.5 cm then this is a peculiarity of your monitor. Then you should compensate by 17.5/18.5 = 0.9459, i.e. try `set size ratio -0.9459` (or maybe the inverse `-1.0571`, depending what is your height and your width).
2. You can format labels via `sprintf()`, e.g. `sprintf("%.1f",value)` or maybe `"%.1g"`. Check `help sprintf` and `help format_specifiers`.
3. From your example, I assume you don't want only *the* maximum, but the *maxima* in quadrant 2 and 4, correct? You can extract the maxima during the first plot. For this you define the functions `dist(dx,dy)` and `getDmax(dx,dy)` the latter will store the line indices for the maximum values in quadrants 2 and 4 in the variables `idxMax2` and `idxMax4`, respectively. In the third plot command you plot the data as vectors from the origin but only for those two indices.
4. Check `help xzeroaxis`.

You can get help for most of the keywords if you type in gnuplot console: `help <your keyword>`.

*Update:*

- show x- and y-label
- labels on max. distance and angle added (check `help atan2`)

**Script:** (I used wxt terminal)

```
### find max distance from origin
reset session

set terminal wxt size 800,800 background "black"
set size ratio -1
set border lc "white"

$Data <<EOD
-6.0    -10.14  -10.10  14.92   14.86
-5.5    -16.75  -16.70  25.60   25.50
-5.0    -20.62  -20.53  30.65   30.49
-4.5    -26.56  -26.42  38.00   37.74
-4.0    -27.80  -27.55  38.25   37.84
-3.5    -33.33  -32.94  43.80   43.19
-3.0    -33.96  -33.37  44.04   43.19
-2.5    -38.02  -37.20  46.64   45.85
-2.0    -38.97  -38.07  44.53   44.18
-1.5    -30.61  -29.97  34.93   35.03
-1.0    -22.60  -22.00  24.24   24.22
-0.5    -7.65   -7.25   5.70    5.47
0.0      2.87    2.84    -3.67   -3.66
0.5      17.62   17.21   -19.79  -19.57
1.0      17.37   16.77   -17.00  -16.95
1.5      30.11   29.50   -32.04  -32.20
2.0      34.69   33.99   -40.26  -40.04
2.5      38.21   37.44   -45.19  -44.37
3.0      34.26   33.67   -42.68  -41.83
3.5      26.69   26.31   -34.85  -34.24
4.0      30.04   29.79   -41.45  -41.03
4.5      20.62   20.48   -28.99  -28.74
EOD

maxv=1
set xlabel "X" tc "white"
set xrange [-maxv:maxv]
set xtics 0.25
set ylabel "Y" tc "white"
set yrange [-maxv:maxv]
set ytics 0.25
set grid xtics ytics lt 1 lc "white" dt 3
set yzeroaxis lt 1 lc "white" lw 1.8 dt 3
set xzeroaxis lt 1 lc "white" lw 1.8 dt 3

set style fill empty border
set obj 1 circle at 0,0  size 0.25 fc "grey"
set style arrow 1 lc "red" lw 2 dt 2 nohead

set key noautotitle
set angles degrees
idxMax2 = idxMax4 = NaN
dmax2   = dmax4   = 0
dist(dx,dy) = sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
getDmax(dx,dy) = dx<0 && dy>0 ? (d=dist(dx,dy),d>dmax2?(dmax2=d,idxMax2=$0):0) : \
                 dx>0 && dy<0 ? (d=dist(dx,dy),d>dmax4?(dmax4=d,idxMax4=$0):0) :NaN

plot $Data u (dx=$2-$3):(dy=$4-$5,getDmax(dx,dy),dy) w l lc "magenta", \
        '' u ($2-$3):($4-$5):(sprintf("%.1f",$1)) w labels tc "white" point pt 7 lc "white" offset char 1,1, \
        '' u ($0==idxMax2 || $0==idxMax4 ? 0 : NaN):(0):($2-$3):($4-$5) w vectors as 1, \
        '' u (f=($0==idxMax2 || $0==idxMax4), dx=($2-$3), dy=($4-$5), \
              f ? dx/2 : NaN):(f ? dy/2 : NaN):(sprintf("%.3f\n%.1f°",dist(dx,dy),atan2(dy,dx))) \
              w labels tc "red" font ",12" offset 3,2
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still, I need the names of the axes... Because of axes labels, plot is not square, but terminal is. With a window of 700x700 pixels, the X-axis is 22 pixels shorter than the Y-axis. I tried to vary "set margins", but this only shifted the plot. Setting the window size to 722x700 did not help either. Is there another way?
The dotted line connecting the most distant points in quadrants 2 and 4 - exactly what was needed. But is it also possible to display (as a title, for example) length value of this line (amplitude between points) and its angle of line (now it is near 135 deg)?

Comment: @oleg518 the canvas (terminal) size is one thing and the graph size is another thing. If you have automargin, gnuplot will determine the necessary margins. One way to get to a defined size of the graph _in pixels_ is for example `set term wxt size 800,800`, `set margins 0,0,0,0`, `set origin 0.1,0.1`, `set size 0.8,0.8`. Check `help origin`, `help size`. Then the graph itself should have a size of 640x640 pixels. Well, then you might need to set x- and y-ranges manually as well. About the other things I will modify my answer maybe later today or tomorrow.